# Pass variable value between two classes in java

Tags: java

I want to access variables `sTerminalId` & `sTransactionId` in Class `ServerThread`

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {

    /* Some Code Omitted Here */

    public void run() {
            String sDataFromPOS="";
            //Get Some Value in sDataFromPOS
            byte[] bSendToPOS = SAXHandler.ParseXMLToString(sDataFromPOS.toString().substring(2));
    }
}

public class SAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    static String sTerminalId = "";
    static String sTransactionId = "";

    public static byte[] ParseXMLToString(String sXMLData) throws Throwable {
        /* Do Some Operation on String sXMLData & extarct value of sTerminalId & sTransactionId*/
    }
}
```

What i tried is

```
SAXHandler.sTerminalId
```

**Will get me value but only for one run if run it again it gives me previous value**.
is there any alternative ? i am dealing with sensitive data so dont want to mess my code

Comment: Create Object and use it

Comment: if you dont want the values of the variables to be overwritten, dont make them static!  especially since you are using multi threading

Comment: if you want to keep ParseXMLToString method static, return object which has byte[], sTerminalId & sTransactionId from that method

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh : I Have Multiple variable to be return by that method showed here only two. and that byte[] return will get deleted auto. once i get answer to my question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why statics are bad. Make the variables instance variables and create a new object instance for each run (let's ignore encapsulation for simplicity):

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        String sDataFromPOS="";
        //Get Some Value in sDataFromPOS
        SAXHandler handler = new SAXHandler();
        byte[] bSendToPOS = handler.parseXMLToString(sDataFromPOS.toString().substring(2));
        handler.sTerminalId .... // access instance variables
    }
}

public class SAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    String sTerminalId = "";
    String sTransactionId = "";

    public byte[] parseXMLToString(String sXMLData) throws Throwable {
        /* Do Some Operation on String sXMLData & extarct value of sTerminalId & sTransactionId*/
    }
}
```

Comment: So, is it ok if create object of class and call non static method inside Thread ? does it have any advantage over static method ?

Comment: Using statics means that all tread instances share the same variables, and I think that's not what you want. Generally, threads should share as few state as possible. Creating objects inside threads is very common, so don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Reinitialize your variable again before processing... like

```
public static byte[] ParseXMLToString(String sXMLData) throws Throwable {

     sTerminalId = "";
     sTransactionId = "";

    }
```

Comment: Is it a most legitimate way to do this ?

Comment: yes this is correct and work.... but it is better to use the approach suggested by noise in about post